# Angular component causing program to fail

Tags: angular

I've been working on an Angular application, and have been following along/tweaking the TOH example from angular, but this particular component is causing my project to fail.

Does anyone see something I don't that might cause this failure?

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { Purchase } from './purchase';
import { PurchaseService } from './purchases.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'purchaseDetails',
  templateUrl: './purchase-detail.component.html'
})
export class PurchaseDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  purchase: Purchase;

  constructor(
    private purchaseService: PurchaseService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.purchaseService.getPurchase(+params.get('id')))
      .subscribe(purchase => this.purchase = purchase);
  }
}
```

The application hangs at the index page with my "Loading..." text

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?  Also, when you remove the component it works?  It's a bit hard to tell with just the component.ts file, there could be issues with file structure, the markup, or a number of things really.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue inside the components HTML file. Should've checked for errors on the webpage! :/